# RabbitMQ on .net core performance

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, .net-core

I am evaluating RabbitMQ with .Net Core Web Api for performance. I creating a web api that will only publish message to a rabbitmq queue and a worker process will pick the message and process it.

We wanted to send about 1000+ messages per second using a web api, i create a new .Net Core Web Application and a class for rabbitmq to sendmessage and hosted the application on local iis.

For load testing i am using a different machine and create a simple jmeter file to post to web api e.g. api/rabbit. This will sendMessage to a queue. I have used Taurus to execute jmeter test for about 60 seconds.

Here is the results

- concurrency @ 50 = 453 hits/s (29ms avg response time)
- concurrency @ 100 = 563 hits/s (174ms avg response time)

Please advise?

QueueAccessLayer

```
public class RMQAccessLayer : IRMQAccessLayer
{
    private ConnectionFactory _factory;
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _model;
    private IBasicProperties _basicProperties;

    public RMQAccessLayer()
    {
        _factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "guest", Password = "guest" };
        _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
        _model = _connection.CreateModel();
        _model.QueueDeclare("hello", true, false, false, null);

        _basicProperties = _model.CreateBasicProperties();
        _basicProperties.Persistent = true;
    }

    public bool SendMessage(string msg)
    {

        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
        _model.BasicPublish("", "hello", _basicProperties, body);

        return true;
    }
}

public interface IRMQAccessLayer
{
    bool SendMessage(string msg);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add RabbitMQ 
        services.AddSingleton<IRMQAccessLayer, RMQAccessLayer>();

    }
```

RabbitController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RabbitController : Controller
{
    private IRMQAccessLayer _queue;
    public RabbitController(IRMQAccessLayer queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
    }
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var emailMessage = "Message Id - " + Guid.NewGuid();
        _queue.SendMessage(emailMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Advise what? What is your question?